# C++ memory addresses of pair cout

Tags: c++, std-pair

When I use the following code I get a mem address(?) before the second item of the pair like this:
666, **0x6090e8**667    666, **0x6090e8**667    666, **0x6090e8**667.

What am I doing wrong?

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > > > total;

int main()
{

  total.resize(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
      total[i].resize(10);
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      total[0][0].push_back(std::make_pair(666,667));
    }

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
      std::cout << total[0][0][i].first << ", " <<
      std::cout << total[0][0][i].second << '\t';
    }
  std:: cout << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: You have an extra `<<` at the end of your first `cout` line.

Comment: Please share with us the expected result, as well.

Comment: Why your compiler didn't detect the error?:  http://ideone.com/zLAar1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::cout << total[0][0][i].first << ", " <<
std::cout << total[0][0][i].second << '\t';
```

Due to the `<<` at the end of the first line, you're outputting `std::cout` (in the second line) into `cout`, as if you typed `std::cout << std::cout;`. Apparently your compiler has an overload or conversion that causes this to display a memory address (although it may fail to compile on other compilers).

Either replace it with a semicolon, or remove the `std::cout <<` from the second line.

Answer (score 0):

For

```
std::cout << total[0][0][i].first << ", " <<
```

you probably meant

```
std::cout << total[0][0][i].first << ", ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `std::cout << total[0][0][i].first << ", " <<`. The extra `<<` at the end of the line (and no semicolon) ends up outputting the next `std::cout` into your first `std::cout` statement.

It behaves like this: `std::cout << std::cout` leading to the address being displayed.

You probably wanted to use:
`std::cout << total[0][0][i].first << ", ";` instead.